# social site link that be open in another window in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How to implement social sites link in rails app. Actually I did the following:

```
<%= link_to "www.linkedin.com/in/raj4057kumar", :target => "_blank", class: "linkedin" do %>
  <%= image_tag("linkedin.png", :alt => "Linkedin") %>
<% end %>
```

But the problem is:

Url being: http://localhost:3000/www.linkedin.com/in/raj4057kumar
while we need like: www.linkedin.com/in/raj4057kumar

How to do this???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because you are not adding the `http://` infront of the url.

Change your code to:

```
<%= link_to "LINK NAME HERE", "http://www.linkedin.com/in/raj4057kumar", :target => "_blank", class: "linkedin" do %> 
<%= image_tag("linkedin.png", :alt => "Linkedin") %> 
<% end %>
```

Comment: I think the purpose of the `do/end` block is so that the image itself will be linked and clickable.

Answer (score 1):

Try inserting `https://` at the beginning for external url

```
<%= link_to 'Raj Kumar', 'https://www.linkedin.com/in/raj4057kumar', target: '_blank', class: 'linkedin' %>
```